# Java EE jta hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files does not work

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I try to import sql file when web application runs. I placed `import.sql` into `src/main/resources/import.sql`. Then I modified my `persistence.xml` by adding `import_files` directive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             version="2.1"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jsp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="spPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <description>SP Persistence Unit</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/SpDS</jta-data-source>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="import.sql"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

But after redeploy or restart server nothing to uploads in database.
I use WildFly 8.1.0, Hibernate 4.3.5.Final, Database h2database 1.3.161.
I tried to remove blank lines from import.sql and change hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to create-drop.
Any idea why import.sql does not load in database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar situation, please check if:

1) You can run your sql script manualy (**No SQL errors are shown when error occurs during import**)

2) Please make sure that all sql statements are **single-lined**, eg:

```
    create table Table1{ column1, column2,etc.};
```

instead of

```
    create table Table1{
     col1 ..,
     col2 ..,
    }
```

I noticed these 2 issues when using import, hope this solves your problem too.

**[UPDATE]** 
Thx to @vsapiha there is support for multiple lines sql:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor">org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.M‌​ultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor</property>
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was in import.sql I used double quotes while should single quotes.

Comment: Glad i could help. I strongly suggest to use import feature only for DEVELOPMENT purposes.

Comment: you can add this configuration key in order to use **multi-line** sql script `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor">org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor</property>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the import files. Hibernate will look by default at **WEB-INF/classes/import.sql**, the place where it will be in your WAR if you place the file where you did. I always use WAR and never had to specify the location of it.

If you use **JAR**, the import goes in the root of the file, according to this [link](https://goldmann.pl/blog/2012/08/24/generate-a-database-schema-with-openjpa-and-hibernate-on-jboss-as-7/). (I never tried it though).

Comment: Yes, it works without specifying import_files, thanks.